# Java in PHP: Executing program by reading from console

Tags: java, php, javac

I am trying to run Java programs in PHP using PHP's `exec()` function. But consider this sample program:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class MyProgram
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
            String name = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Hi " + name);
        }//end main
    }//end class MyProgram
```

But the problem is that when I execute one such program, I get the error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:7)
```

This is probably because on my web browser I have a console lacking. IDEs such as eclipse, netbeans, terminal/command prompt provide me with one, but how do I provide one for a web browser?

Sample PHP Code:

```
    <?php
        exec('javac MyProgram.java 2>&1');
        exec('java MyProgram 2>&1', $output);

        print_r($output);
    ?>
```

Comment: Have you tested this in isolation from PHP?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but `System.in` should read from console, so unless you have no console, you do not have anything to read from.

Comment: Please provide the PHP code that you're using when invoking the "Java" program.

Comment: Perhaps you should pass some data to the `STDIN` of the newly created process.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.proc-open.php. It gives you access to the file STD(IN/OUT/ERR) handlers so you can pass input to your program

Comment: Done, check out the php code